# How to set code style in *.blade.php file using phpstorm

Tags: php, formatting, phpstorm

`Ctrl+Alt+L` is the short key it's set my code on `html`, `css`, `php` but when I use this on `.blade.php` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the plugin for blade support or the plugin for Laravel?

[[image: 1]]

If not, do so and try again. In your settings, there is no specific option for setting a code style for "blade" files, but phpStorm can recognize the language of each code line in your blade.php file, so it will apply either the HTML code style in HTML lines, or JS code style in JS lines and so on. Try to set them to your needs and then use your shortcut. Also, please check if your shortcut is correct.